# Shiny - two selectInput and one checkbox in one line

Tags: r, shiny

how to make 2 selectInput and one checkbox in one line, the display will be like this:

x axis : -----    y axis : -------      -check

and the code is :
UI :

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shiny"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

    ),
    mainPanel(

      uiOutput("scatcoefgwr")
    )
  )
))
```

server :

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$scatcoefgwr <- renderUI({

    list(

      selectInput("axisx", "x axis:",choices = c("1","2","3")),
      selectInput("axisy", "y axis:",choices = c("1","2","3")),
      checkboxInput("scatterD3_ellipsesgwr", "check", value = FALSE)
    )
  })

})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way using columns

```
#ui.R
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shiny"),
  fluidRow(
    column(width=2,uiOutput("one")),   
    column(width=2,uiOutput("two")),
    column(width=2,uiOutput("three"))
  )
))
```

change the widths as you need.

```
#server.R
shinyServer(function(input, output) { 
  output$one <- renderUI({
    list(
      selectInput("axisx", "x axis:",choices = c("1","2","3"))
    )
  })
  output$two <- renderUI({
    list(
      selectInput("axisy", "y axis:",choices = c("1","2","3"))
    )
  })
  output$three <- renderUI({
    list(
      checkboxInput("scatterD3_ellipsesgwr", "check", value = FALSE)
    )
  })
})
```